# Combining dynamic_cast and std::any_cast

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there any safe `std::any_cast` and `dynamic_cast` combination?

I'm trying to perform the following:

```
struct V
{
    virtual void x( ) { std::cout << "V"; }
};

struct A: V
{
    void x( ) override { std::cout << "A"; }
};

struct B: V
{
    void x( ) override { std::cout << "B"; }
};

struct C: A, B
{
    void x( ) override { std::cout << "C"; }
};

int main( )
{
    // In my code, I cannot change the template argument
    // to be a base class and construct it with a child
    // class due to requirements of my implementation
    auto c = std::make_any< C >( );
#if 0 // doesn't work
    std::any_cast< B >( c ).x( );
    std::any_cast< A >( c ).x( );
#else // works, but requires knowing the type is C
    dynamic_cast< B && >( std::any_cast< C >( c ) ).x( );
    dynamic_cast< A && >( std::any_cast< C >( c ) ).x( );
#endif
}
```

Comment: don't forget to add a virtual destructor to `V`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining static\_cast and std::any\_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313749/combining-static-cast-and-stdany-cast)

Comment: @j6t That is my question, asked at the same time. It does not answer my question, since this is about RTTI not CTTI.

Comment: The `#else` branch doesn't actually need `dynamic_cast`. `static_cast` would work just as well there. No RTTI is necessary when up-casting from derived to base class.

Comment: The reason why your cast that you are asking for here will not work is the same as in the other question you asked: `std::any` cannot answer "which type do you have", it can only answer "do you have this type X". I.e., you, the programmer, must know which type you expect, exactly what you are doing in the `#else` branch of the code you show.