# Combining static_cast and std::any_cast

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there any safe `std::any_cast` and `static_cast` combination?

I'm trying to perform the following:

```
#include <any>
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    auto x = std::make_any< int >( 5 );
#if 0 // doesn't work
    std::cout << std::any_cast< short >( x );
#else // works, but requires knowing the initial type
    std::cout << static_cast< short >( std::any_cast< int >( x ) );
#endif
}
```

Comment: The type of `x` is `std::any`.  So `std::any_cast<stored_type>`is the preferred way, and the safest, Whatever that means when using std::any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get a value out of `std::any` is `any_cast<T>` where `T` has the same `typeid` as the value inside (you can inspect it with `.type()` method).

If you need other semantics, e.g. "take a value iff it's convertible to `int`", you have to use something else for type erasure. For example, you can write one yourself.

Comment: How would one go about writing their own `std::any` with such functionality? How does one track `static_cast` conversions? Or must they be hardcoded?

Comment: @j5w I suspect [CppCon 2019 Back to Basics Type Erasure talk by Arthur O'Dwyer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbUCHifyT24) gives a good overview, although I didn't watch it myself

Comment: Great video! It even addresses an approach to afford `dynamic_cast` capabilities. It unfortunately doesn't address anything about `static_cast`, so I may need to hard-code it and track `typeid` instead of relying on vtables or the exception model's RTTI.

Comment: @j5w I consider `static_cast` just another capability. E.g. `virtual optional<int> try_static_cast_to_int()` and there are two branches in the implementation: one for convertible, one for all others. You can differentiate between two with `if constexpr` and `std::is_convertible` in the inner templated class.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is, that `std::any` cannot make sense of the data that is stores.

You may think that there is a member function `type()`, so `std::any` *can* know the type. But actually, that does not help, because the only thing you can do with the result of `type()` is to compare it to some other typeid. That is, you must already know for which type you are checking.
Consequently, `std::any` cannot really answer the question "which type do you carry?"; it can only answer the question "do you carry this type X?".

The latter happens when you call `std::any_cast<short>`: `std::any` only knows that it does not carry a `short`, but it does not really know that it carries a type that is convertible to `short`.

Comment: Is there anyway to create such automatic casting as an extension to `std::any`, since this kind of casting is done at compile-time?

Comment: @j5w No you cannot, because you have to extend at two points: a) in `any_cast`; b) in all constructor calls to `std::any` which theoretically may be out of your control.